# How to effectively monitor MONGO

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, health-monitoring

We need a software (preferably free :) that can monitor mongo in production for us. We have used a few commands that come with mongo to monitor it but it does not give us "slow queries" for example. Or blocked collections due to high number of insertions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [MongoDB Management Service](https://mms.mongodb.com), which allows to monitor up to 8 MongoDB instances for free and gives detailed and useful graphs and stats.